# Can't change font-size from JS in IE 8-9

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-9

I'm using ContentFlow JS library and I have a problem in IE (8 and 9, older versions I don't plan to support). ContentFlow's scripts can't adjust font size in the carousel.
In Chrome, FireFox, Safari, Safari (iOS) everything works fine.

Can anyone suggest reasons for such behavior in IE?

**Chrome:**
[image]
**Internet Explorer:**
[image]

Some code as requested:

Carousel element code:

```
<div class="item" id="backstage1">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="video-title">Конференции</div>
        <div class="video-event">
            <strong>Microsoft TechEd</strong>
        </div>
        <img id="banner1" class="ibanner bordered" src="img/video/c1.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <img class="shadow" src="img/flow-item-shadow.png" alt="" title="" />
    </div>
    <div class="caption">Some description text</div>
</div>
```

CSS for element:

```css
.video-title {
    font-family: "FSAlbertPro", "Arial", serif;
    font-size: 3.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0.9em;
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    margin-bottom: -8px;
    position: relative;
}

.video-event {
    position: relative;
    top: 28px;
    left: 15px;
    font-family: "FSAlbertPro", "Arial", serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

Other "magic" is done by ContentFlow.

p.s. trying to make a jsFiddle to recreate the problem... will update.

Comment: Didn't you forget to post the code? `:P`

Comment: No, we can't suggest anything without you, providing some codes! from screen-shots we can't guess anything!

Comment: I think you have not posted enough code to replicate your problem. Perhaps you can make us a jsFiddle that shows your problem in action?

Comment: @ChrisNielsen - Sometimes it might be hard to recreate the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make a jsFiddle. I'm newbie here, so it will take some time...

Comment: @Derek In many cases, the act of attempting to recreate the problem will lead one to the solution. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your font sizes are in em. I think, IE uses bigger font than firefox or chrome by default. Try to specify font size in px to body, and take attention for headings!

Comment: When I converted font-size from em to px the problem started to occur in Chrome/FF/Safari also :(

Comment: Then I've tried to change px to % - Chrome/FF/Safari are ok, IE - not